# How to implement image variable in components from different paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below structure in my React project:

```
-images/
 |
  -image.svg
-components/
 |
  -SomeComponent1.js
  -some_folder/
   |
    -SomeComponent2.js
-utils
 |
  -utils.js
```

What I have in `utils.js`:

```
import image from "../images/image.svg";

export const ImageComponent = props => {
        return (
              <img src={image}/>
            )
        );
    };
```

I use the above `ImageComponent` in components `SomeComponent1` and `SomeComponent2` (IRL I have more components), but it doesn't work, because image source path is different in these components (`../images/image` and `../../images/image` respectively).

How to realize this logic?

Comment: use an absolute path instead?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Are you about `D:\some\way\to\project\src\images\image`? O_o

Comment: absolute to the project root should be enough, so probably `/images/image.svg` in your case. But then again I have no idea how these things work on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require` to load the image.

If your paths are relative to ImageComponent, then you can use `require` in ImageComponent only as shown in below code.

```
export const ImageComponent = ({ src }) => {
  return (
      <img src={require(src)} alt="" />
  );
};
// Load component as below
<ImageComponent src={"../images/image.svg"} />
```

Otherwise, you can use `require` were in the prop value, when you are loading the ImageComponent.

```
export const ImageComponent = ({ src }) => {
  return (
      <img src={src} alt="" />
  );
};

// Load component as below
<ImageComponent src={require("../images/image.svg")} />
```

Just make sure images are relative to the file from where you are calling them.

Comment: No, I just want to insert imported image in `utils.js` file, and then load component `<ImageComponent/>` in `SomeComponent1.js` and `SomeComponent2.js` without `src={require("../images/image.svg")}` in props you suggest